# live convert audio stream from microphone to ACC - iphone

Tags: iphone, encoding, core-audio

I'm developing a library to convert live stream from microphone to ACC format using iphone hardware. I'm successful to make it work. However, the result file has a problem with it. Every sound packet has a glitch at the end. It will make a sound like "bop bop"! So weird!

I uploaded a sample to media fire via the link http://www.mediafire.com/?4mhrb9p6m2j5csd

you can download and listen to it so you can find out the "glitch"

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you very much,

Qaun